# SAP HANA and Visual Studio Community Data Source

Tags: c#, hana

1. I downloaded SAP HANA CLIENT package and installed it according to documentation.
2. I am trying to add a connection to HANA database in Visual Studio Community however I am not able to choose **Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for SAP HANA** to create a data connection - there is no such option.
3. According to the documentation - client package works with VS 2010 and later.
4. After I installed client software I got the following message:

   > Installing HANA ADO.NET for Visual Studio 2010..... Succeeded.

So the problem is - I am not able to indicate proper Data Source for HANA database in VS Community and that is why I am not able to use Entity Framework to work with the database. Is it possible that VS Community does not support this Data Source?

Currently I am downloading VS 2010 Ultimate - but I don't wanna give up on Community.

**[UPDATE 1]**
I followed this article - http://blog.nwoolls.com/2012/07/25/registering-missing-data-providers-with-visual-studio-2012/ by Nathanial Woolls and after some modifications it worked for me and Visual Studio 2010 (on different host and clean installation of VS).

**[UPDATE 2 + WORKAROUND]**
Read my MS post if needed - [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a0aa1d6-d46d-4833-8042-03216ea5f320/sap-hana-client-and-visual-studio-community?forum=vssetup)

Answer (score 0):

1. Install VS2010 or Higher version.
2. Match OS bit version and Visual Studio bit version if both are same then installed respective SAP HANA client but if both bit version is mismatch then install 32 bit and 64 bit both version of SAP HANA client in you machine.
3. Check file is available accessible or not in reseptive folder location or not e.g (C:\Program Files\sap\hdbclient\libadonetHDB.dll,C:\Program Files\sap\hdbclient\libSQLDBCHDB)